# How to delete the default button in CPropertySheet Wizard MFC application?

Tags: mfc, cpropertysheet, classwizard

Hey guys..I am designing a set-up wizard using CPropertySheet and CpropertyPage in MFC application...I have completed the design but the thing is..In normal CProperty Sheet there are four default buttons "BACK NEXT FINISH HELP"...but I want only NEXT and FINISH buttons ...I used the following code to do that but its giving me a run time error.stating.."stack overflow"
I am not sure where exactly to include this code(i mean in which class)..nor how to utilize this function.. can any one help me..

> BOOL
>   CExtractorFinalUIDlg::OnSetActive() {
>    CSelfExtractor *setButtons =
>   (CSelfExtractor*)GetParent();
>    setButtons->SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_NEXT
>   | PSWIZB_FINISH | PSWIZB_CANCEL);
>
> return
>   CExtractorFinalUIDlg::OnSetActive();
>
> }

Comment: Could you show your CPropertySheet/CPropertyPage classes code? It's difficult to say just with this snapshot.
In the snapshoot I can see that CSelfExtractor setButtons should be a pointer, but I suppose it's ok in your real code because it would not compile otherwise.

Comment: tanx 4 ur reply Javier De Pedro,what u said was correct its actually a pointer..i made a mistake wen typing that...i will redefine the above function again...

BOOL CPropertyPage::onsetActive()
{
   CPropertySheet *setButtons = (CPropertSheet)GetParent();
   setButtons->SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_NEXT | PSWIZB_FINISH);
   return CExtractorFinalUIDlg::OnSetActive();
}

is that clear now

Comment: tanx 4 ur reply Javier De Pedro,what u said was correct its actually a pointer..i made a mistake wen typing that...i will redefine the above function again...

BOOL CPropertyPage::onsetActive()
{
   CPropertySheet *setButtons = (CPropertSheet)GetParent();
   setButtons->SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_NEXT | PSWIZB_FINISH);
   return CExtractorFinalUIDlg::OnSetActive();
}

is that clear now

Comment: Yes, this is clear. I can't see any problem in this code...but I would  need to see the whole thing to know what's happening. Sorry but I can not help you without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of your propertysheet, insert

```
m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_NOAPPLYNOW;
```

The m_psh is of type [PROPSHEETHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774546%28VS.85%29.aspx), you can set a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

The actual cause of the stack overflow is that you call CExtractorFinalUIDlg::OnSetActive() in the CExtractorFinalUIDlg::OnSetActive(). So the function calls itself recursively. This leads to the stack overflow.

The function could be something like:

```
BOOL CExtractorFinalUIDlg::OnSetActive() {
     CPropertySheet* sheet = (CPropertySheet*) GetParent();
     ASSERT(sheet);
     // Combination of PSWIZB_NEXT and PSWIZB_FINISH might be useless
     sheet->SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_NEXT | PSWIZB_FINISH | PSWIZB_CANCEL)

     return CPropertyPage::OnSetActive();
}
```

Look up [MSDN: CPropertySheet::SetWizardButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex7e7b4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more infos.